# Counting kilometers/lines with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, borders, count, feature-count

I am trying to get a measure of border intensity of different regions in Europe.

Having a relevant shapefile of European countries at the regional level (NUTS2) as well several ones by century for a relatively long period, I would like to get the kilometers of borders within each region, historically.

Is there a way to get this measure with ArcGIS Desktop?

First, I uploaded the shapefile of European countries at the regional level (today) as well as the shapefiles by century (transformed from Polygon to Line). But I don't know how to get the kilometers of lines crossing each region nor the number of line crossing the regions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool specific to find neighbouring polygons and their shared boundary, which is called [Polygon Neighbors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm):

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
>   coincident edges, or nodes).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool. The polyline features should be the lower rank if you're trying to find the length and count of lines that intersect each unique region.  You can then create a Length field and [Calculate Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) in Kilometers [km] on the newly created field.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. To be honest, I followed this itinerary but obtained rather odd results. I mean, I used the Intersect tool, put the polyline features after (below) the NUTS shapefile; created then a Length field and calculated Geometry in kilometers.

However, I had a few issues : some regions were multiplied. ie. appeared several times, with each a time a length assigned. Also, some results were purely bizarre. i.e regions close to the borders with less length assigned than some in the centre.

Thank you very much,